# Jquery или js value select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На гугле сделал поиск, но не нашел ответ на мой вопрос, сразу говорю, за акцент извините — не русский.

`html`:

```html
<select name="ertuxi" id="ertuxi" class="custom-select">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<!--== Pick Up Location ==-->

<!--== Pick Up Date ==-->
<div class="pick-up-date book-item">
  <h4>PICK-UP DATE:</h4>
  <select name="jam" id="jam" class="custom-select">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option value="1">01։00</option>
    <option value="2">07։00</option>
    <option value="3">09։00</option>
    <option value="4">11։00</option>
    <option value="5">13։00</option>
    <option value="6">15։00</option>
    <option value="7">17։00</option>
    <option value="8">20։00
    </option>
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь выберет на первом селекторе например, `<option>` 3 из второго селектора удалились все `<option>` и остался только один `<option>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю так вы хотели:

```js
function update(e) {
  let target = document.getElementById('jam');
  let ob = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
  target.value = ob.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="ertuxi" id="ertuxi" class="custom-select" onchange="update(event.target)">
  <option selected>Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<!--== Pick Up Location ==-->

<!--== Pick Up Date ==-->
<div class="pick-up-date book-item">
  <h4>PICK-UP DATE:</h4>
  <select name="jam" id="jam" class="custom-select">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option value="1">01։00</option>
    <option value="2">07։00</option>
    <option value="3">09։00</option>
    <option value="4">11։00</option>
    <option value="5">13։00</option>
    <option value="6">15։00</option>
    <option value="7">17։00</option>
    <option value="8">20։00
    </option>
```